# How get acces to response.data value in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, request

I want do set data in my component by http requests, but outside $http.get data is undefined.

How get response data outside $http.get?

```
'use strict';
 angular.
 module('filesApp').
 component('filesList', {
  template:
      '<ul>' +
        '<li ng-repeat="file in $ctrl.files">' +
          '<span>{{file.data1}}</span>' +
          '<p><a href="{{file.data2}}">Create</a></p>' +               
        '</li>' +
      '</ul>',      
  controller: function FilesListController($http, $scope) {
      //need response.data here
              $http.get('/api/1').then(function (response) {
              if (response.data.error) {
                  return null;
              } else {                      
                  $http.get('/api/2' + response.data).then(function (response) {
                      if (response.data.error) {
                          return null;
                      } else {                              
                          //response.data contains data that I need.                              
                          return response.data;
                      }
                  });
              }
          });          
  }
});
```

Comment: Store it in the scope once $http.get is done, so it will available in the component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store `response.data` on the scope, so you can use it in the view.

```
'use strict';
 angular.module('filesApp')
    .component('filesList', {
        template:
            '<ul>' +
                '<li ng-repeat="file in $ctrl.files">' +
                    '<span>{{file.data1}}</span>' +
                    '<p><a href="{{file.data2}}">Create</a></p>' +               
                '</li>' +
            '</ul>',      
        controller: function FilesListController($http, $scope) {
              $http.get('/api/1').then(function (firstResponse) {
                  if (firstResponse.data.error) {
                      return null;
                  } else {                      
                      $http.get('/api/2' + firstResponse.data).then(function (secondResponse) {
                          if (secondResponse.data.error) {
                              return null;
                          } else {
                              $scope.files = secondResponse.data;
                          }
                  });
              }
          });          
      }
});
```

Comment: $scope.files is undefined outside first  $http.get

Comment: Where are you trying to use it?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. Certainly the simplest is to store the response data in a variable in the scope. E.g.

```
controller: function FilesListController($http, $scope) {
   //need response.data here
   $http.get('/api/1').then(function (response) {
      if (response.data.error) {
          return null;
      } else {                      
          $http.get('/api/2' + response.data).then(function (response) {
              if (response.data.error) {
                  return null;
              } else {                              
                  //response.data contains data that I need.  
                  $scope.dataYouNeed = response.data;                            
              }
          });
      }
  });
```

}

You can the display it somewhere in your view with `{{dataYouNeed}}`.